# Using pickle to write and read files in python with multiple processes

Tags: python, mpi, pickle

I am using mpi4py and want to write and read pickle files in the process. I keep getting errors like

```
return pickle.load(open(filename, "rb"))
EOFError: Ran out of input
```

I am pretty sure this is because a thread is trying to read a file that is currently open to write by another thread. How can I make pickle MPI-safe?

Comment: Start by checking the file is **not** empty before loading it.

Answer (score 1):

Use `with open(my_file, 'rb') as xxx` to open file and/or use Lock

Comment: are you sure this is making it MPI save? I still get the same error...